# Exacttarget SOAP API - How to retrieve list from Job ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Is there a way to supply the Job ID and retrieve the lists the mailing was sent to?

for example, if i have a job ID (12344556), i would like to do a call to the API to know what list that specific Job was sent to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a retrieve on the ListSend object. An example of this can be found here... https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_lists_for_a_send